Unicode string not being read correctly
I'm reading an HTML file using Java and am having some trouble with a Unicode character. The problematic statement is:
<span class="xml-lang" lang="cmn-Hant" xml:lang="cmn-Hant"></span>

The character is
    (f0 a6 ae bc)
Whereas I read in
ম¼    (e0 a6 ae c2 bc)
It's close but obviously wrong.
The file I'm reading is marked utf-8 (and I'm reading it in as utf-8) and has LOADS of other CJK strings that get read in perfectly.
I'm hoping  someone can simply look at these strings and understand how the f0 -> e0 and the introduction of c2.
Any ideas?

Two things. First, HTML is not XML and does not support namespaces. xml:lang is straight up invalid HTML code. Second, the HTML lang attribute uses BCP 47, which would be zh-cmn-Hant in this case. But as a Stackoverflow thing: remember to show your ([mcve]) code, just in case you're doing something "obviously" wrong that your eyes just keep skipping over and you need a second pair of eyes to spot.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  You're right - I should have said XHTML file. As for the language tag - that's how it was written. I'm processing 1000 epub books  and have found lots of inconsistencies in the files. I know I should give a simple example but it's pretty complex (I need a library to open the epub file, parse it, give me an InputStream, etc.). The code works perfectly for all of the other files (which contain all sorts of Unicode strings) so I was hoping that someone who knows more than me can simply say "it looks like something along the way is treating this as utf-16 instead of utf-8".

Seeing the exact code that deals with the text would be very helpful, but if that’s not possible: Could you test what happens when you read in the character  (code point U+10000)? I tried and failed to find a numerical connection between the source string and the incorrect output string in any encoding, but maybe seeing how the program handles astral characters in general could lead to something.

@SanderSmith the point of a [mcve] is to not have your full workflow: instead of loading in a file, create a String with the (reduced) XHTML content, just enough to trigger the error. No need for any external files or dependencies there. And then apply that same logic everywhere else: hardcode what you can, and literally just delete everything that isn't directly involved in reproducing the problem. Ultimately you're trying to reduce your Java program until it's effectively a hello world class with a public static void main and a bunch of finals for the data your code will need.

(Actually sitting down to reduce your code --so: don't write new code, literally take the code you have and start slashing-- is a pretty typical part of debugging a weird problem: it forces you find what is and isn't relevant, and more times than not, lets you find the problem all on your own simply by throwing away everything that's unrelated. At some point you have so little code left that the problem effectively reveals itself)

Instead of editing your question, you should have provided an answer.

I wrote most of the code I was running 20 years ago and it has worked perfectly since then. The data was passing through several libraries that I had some amount of confidence in. I couldn't figure out who could be changing the data.
The first problem is that the character involved is 4 bytes and didn't print correctly in my output. In my code I try several fonts and the last one I try is Unifont, which I was lead to believe never fails since it contains all of the possible codepoints (HAHA, nope, not even close).
So I fired up the debugger in Eclipse to try and track down what was happening. When I looked at the data, that one character was changed. But it really wasn't, it was perfect, the debugger was showing me an inaccurate view of the world.
It took a little while, but I finally figured out that my code and libraries were working perfectly and this ended up being a font problem. I'm not sure what the deal is with this 4-byte character, but none of the "typical" CJK fonts seems to have it. I eventually tracked down a font that contained the character, and now everything works fine.
